# Some emails not sent codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail, email

I am trying to send mass emails via **Codeigniter** email library. However, only the first few emails are sent successfully.

Here is my `Mail_model`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Mail_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('email');

    }

    public function send_mail($email, $firstname, $data){

        $subject = $data['subject'];
        $message = 'Dear '.$firstname.',<br /><br />'.$data['message'].'<br />'.DOMAIN_NAME;

        //configure email settings
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
        $config['smtp_host'] = SMTP_HOST; //smtp host name
        $config['smtp_port'] = SMTP_PORT; //smtp port number
        $config['smtp_user'] = FROM_EMAIL;
        $config['smtp_pass'] = FROM_PASSWORD; //$from_email password
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
        $config['validation'] = TRUE;
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        //send mail
        $this->email->from(FROM_EMAIL, DOMAIN_NAME);
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);

        //echo json_encode($this->email->print_debugger());
        $this->email->send();      

    }//end method send_mail


  }//end class
```

Here is the bit of code from my controller that I am calling `send_mail` function from the model

```
$customers = $this->customer_model->get_customers();

                foreach($customers as $customer){

                    $this->mail_model->send_mail($customer['email'], $customer['firstname'], $this->input->post());
                    sleep(10);

                }
```

I added `sleep(10)` at the end of the loop to see if everything will work fine but it does not help. I am using **Gmail**.

Comment: Please debug it and paste the output. Add this line: $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: I have. No unusual error messages. All sent show `Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol`. No more messages printed after the last one sent. The rest of the emails are not sent

Comment: did you read googles Bulk Senders Guidelines @  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126